# Fetch instagram posts from specific account

Tags: php, cron, instagram, instagram-api

For some of our clients we used the public instagram API to obtain all the posts from the specific account.

With a cronjob we imported the new posts by schedule. We read the JSON from https://www.instagram.com/{client_account}}/?__a=1 and imported this into our own database for further use.

Unfortunately, due to the recent events at Facebook, Instagram shut down this public API.
The solution for this would be to fetch the new data from Instagram through the instagram API, right? 
The only problem is that we are building a completely automated import and Instagram tells me that I should redirect the user to the authentication URL with a callback url as a parameter where the user gets back at when the login is successful. But when I am trying to make a server to server communication without any user interaction I cannot build in this step. So how do I obtain my Access token?

Is it possible to obtain an access token without the redirect step? Maybe based on the client secret or something like that?

Please advise :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to follow the steps they describe in their API documentation.  The user would only need to authenticate once and then you would store the access token.  You can then make a request on behalf of the user to /user/self/media/recent to grab the latest posts.

Comment: @james_tookey The access token would expire after some time wouldn't it? Than I'll have to create some module where the user can reauthenticate when needed. Thanks!

Comment: @PKL yes, the token seems to expire on average around every 2 months. So you would have to include some functionality where the user can re-auth.